# Simple HTML dom css selector not working

Tags: php, css, dom, css-selectors, simple-html-dom

in reference to http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I have this code:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$x = '<span style="font-family:symbol">&#174;</span>';
$dom = str_get_html($x);
$lis = $dom->find('[style=~font-family:symbol]');
print_r($lis);
```

Which tries to find tags whose style has the font-family:symbol in it using a css selector.

However this returns nothing.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question at all, it would be better to use a CSS class than inline style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [the doc](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) carefully... The available attributes filter are :

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       Filter       |                                      Description                                       |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [attribute]        | Matches elements that have the specified attribute.                                    |
| [!attribute]       | Matches elements that don't have the specified attribute.                              |
| [attribute=value]  | Matches elements that have the specified attribute with a certain value.               |
| [attribute!=value] | Matches elements that don't have the specified attribute with a certain value.         |
| [attribute^=value] | Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it starts with a certain value. |
| [attribute$=value] | Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it ends with a certain value.   |
| [attribute*=value] | Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it contains a certain value.    |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So in your case, you can use the last one for example [the following is tested and it works]:

```
$lis = $dom->find('[style*="font-family:symbol"]');
```

Comment: Huh. So it doesn't actually support the `~=` selector (while supporting some non-standard ones such as `[!attribute]` and `!=`). That's bizarre. To be fair, the documentation for Simple HTML DOM sucks - I still can't figure out where you found this table after looking at the documentation again.

Comment: @BoltClock `How to find HTML elements?` > `Attribute Filters`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quoted the font stuff in your XPath. The `find()` call should be

```
$lis = $dom->find('[style=~"font-family:symbol"]');
                           ^------------------^---- missing
```

Comment: hm I tried $dom->find('[style=~"font-family:symbol"]'); and it's still returning nothing